# В Django проекте на http://localhost/ запускается Apache2 Default Page (ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: django, nginx, docker, apache2, uwsgi

Запускаю докером, uwsgi и nginx django проект и на localhost, и на других доменах открывается Apache2 Default Page, не знаю что это и как исправить.

Вот мой docker-compose.yml код:

```
services:

  db:
    image: postgres:14.5
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  
  cache:
    image: redis:7.0.4
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data/cache:/data

  web:
    build: .
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "uwsgi", "--ini", "/code/config/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini"]
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=educa.settings.prod
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.23.1
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/templates
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

config/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
socket=/code/educa/uwsgi_app.sock
chdir = /code/educa/
module=educa.wsgi:application
master=true
chmod-socket=666
vacuum=true
```

config/nginx/default.conf.template:

```
upstream uwsgi_app {
    server unix:/code/educa/uwsgi_app.sock;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.educaproject.com educaproject.com;
    error_log    stderr warn;
    access_log   /dev/stdout main;

    location / {
        include      /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass   uwsgi_app;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй открыть по адресу - 127.0.0.1

А также убедись в том, что ввел команду

```
python manage.py runserver
```